# User input filename in python to import a variable in file error

Tags: python, input, python-import

I am trying to access a variable that holds a list in another python file A from python file B.

file B has:

```
import file A
A.x
```

when I write import file A directly python accesses the file and variable.

However, my actual goal is to ask user to input the file name, so when I write the code:

```
in = input("give filename")
import in
in.x
```

I get an error that "in" is not a module name

I also tried

```
from in import x
```

which also has the same error

Comment: `import file A` is a syntax error.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Also, `in` is a reserved word.  You can't have a module or variable named that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mod = __import__(input('Enter module name:'))
mod.x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather odd functionality.

First of all, when using `input` you are getting data as a string. The `import` statement cannot process that. You would have to use `exec`, which is already a matter of concern for me.

```
exec(f'import {in}')
```

Second, you should not be storing data into a python file. You should be using JSON, pickle, etc.

Third reason, you are using reserved python words, such as `in` for your variables. `in` is a python statements that allows you to check if an element is within a container. By assigning a variable to it, you are removing this functionality from `in`.